# Is mana generated by a sacrifice ability permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

I have a couple of [Generator Servant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Generator%20Servant) cards.

They have

> {T}, Sacrifice Generator Servant: Add {2} to your mana pool. If that
> mana is spent on a creature spell, it gains haste until end of turn.
> (That creature can attack and {T} as soon as it comes under your
> control.)

Must this mana be used immediately or can it be used in a future round?

And if it's used, does it disappear forever after being used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All mana empties from your mana pool at the end of each step or phase. So you must use it within the same step. All mana that is spent is, well, "spent", it's gone; you can't use it again.

The steps of a turn are:

1. Beginning Phase

   - a. Untap step
   - b.Upkeep step
   - c. Draw step
2. First Main Phase
3. Combat Phase

   - a. Beginning of combat step
   - b. Declare attackers step
   - c. Declare blockers step
   - d. Combat damage step
   - e. End of combat step
4. Second Main Phase
5. Ending Phase

   - a. End step
   - b. Cleanup step

I recommend reading through the [Basic Rulebook](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf), because understanding what happens with generated mana is fundamental to playing the game.

> Mana pool:
>   The place where your mana is stored until you spend it.
>   When mana gets added to your mana pool, it stays there
>   until you spend it or until the current step or phase ends.